# how to concatenate two env variables in the jenkins pipeline with a slash in between?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, concatenation, jenkins-pipeline

I have a script that sends a generated RPM to Nexus OSS manager. The stage in Jenkins is:

```groovy
stage ('nexus deploy') {
  env.REPONAME = "snapshots"
  sh '''
    mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl="${env.NEXUS_URL}/$env.REPONAME"
    '''
  }
```

I have set up the env variable `env.NEXUS_URL` but calling it with two variables side by side with a slash in between somehow doesn't detect the variables and the build is failing with error.

```
-Durl="${env.NEXUS_URL}/$REPONAME": bad substitution
```

Comment: Your `mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl="${env.NEXUS_URL}/$env.REPONAME"` is executing on the shell, and `env.NEXUS_URL` and `env.REPONAME` are both invalid shell substitutions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are confusing the `groovy` syntax and the syntax in `shell`.
you can use `env.VAR` in `groovy` and you can use `${VAR}` between `sh '..'`:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '3'))
    }

    environment {
        NEXUS_URL = 'https://mynexus.com'
        REPONAME    = 'myrepo'
    }

    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                echo "print env vars in groovy"
                echo "my nexus is " + env.NEXUS_URL + " any my repo name is " + env.REPONAME
                sh 'echo "env vars in sh"'
                sh 'echo "nexus is ${NEXUS_URL} and my repo name is ${REPONAME}"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[Pipeline] echo
print env vars in groovy
[Pipeline] echo
my nexus is https://mynexus.com any my repo name is myrepo
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ echo 'env vars in sh'
env vars in sh
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ echo 'nexus is https://mynexus.com and my repo name is myrepo'
nexus is https://mynexus.com and my repo name is myrepo
```

In your case you need:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=${NEXUS_URL}/${REPONAME}
```